# Is it possible to create an action upon the current date expiring date set in a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a table named events in ActiveAdmin.

There is a field called eventdate and in here there is a date of the event.

I am looking to be able to have an action that when the current date is over the event date the table gets an automatic selection in a selectbox called 'event ended'. This basically says the event is expired.

Is this possible or is there a gem that does this already for ActiveAdmin?

Sorry its such a basic question but this is all I have got.

Cheers

Comment: Could you please try explaining it slightly better. What do you mean by `to have an action` - Controller action? 'selectbox' - dropdown? `the table gets an automatic selection` - what table? Datbase table, table in the view, other?

Comment: Hi BroiSatse, Sorry, yeah the table view in activeadmin itself. Really bad explanation. When I say action I mean a way for the event to have the select box 'event_type' to have 'ended' auto selected or expired.

Comment: Are there any other options in this select box? And why would you like to give a user a chance to change it? Wouldn't label be better here?

Comment: Its so in the frontend I can basically get the classes 'expired' and add any item that has expired into an expired list underneath the current events that are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define define two things on your Event model: `expired` scope, and `expired?` method:

```
class Event < AR::Base
  scope :expired, -> { where('eventdate < ?', Date.today) }

  def expired?
    eventdate < Date.today
  end
end
```

To list all expired events you can simply call:

```
Event.expired
```

If you are listing all the events and want to add some custom logic for expired one, you can wrap this logic in `if event.expired?`.

You probably also should inverse scope as well:

```
scope :not_expired, -> { where.not('eventdate < ?', Date,today) }
```

Comment: ah great just having a look now, so how could i then compare date.today with the date of the event in the field? ps is `Date,today` meant to be `Date.today`?

Comment: @Mdunbavan - yep, that's a typo. I'm not sure I understand your question - you already have a method above to compare those values.

Comment: yeah the name of the attribute is `eventdate` is in this example `date` meant to be the name of the attribute?

Comment: @Mdunbavan - my bad again. :) I'll update the answer

Comment: I second guessed and did this and it worked perfectly, your a genius :)) thanks